# Find exact string in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

Currently, I'm trying to find a string in a webpage DOM by doing

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '{0}')]".format(text))
```

However, this finds all instances with that text as a substring.

Is it possible to find the exact text only? and not contains text?

Comment: Can you share HTML sample of target element?

Answer (score 1):

```
//*[text()='string']
```

will return exact matching strings only.
Whereas,

```
//*[contains(text(),'string')]
```

will return everything with substring as 'string'.

Comment: doing `return self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()= translate('{0}', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')]".format(text))` tells me that it is unable to locate the element

Comment: Thanks for saving my life :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `normalize-space()` as follows:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(translate(normalize-space(.), 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), '{0}')]".format(text))
```

Comment: Given xpath expression "//*[normalize-space()=(translate(text(),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), 'log in')]" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression

Comment: @Rohil Checkout my updated answer and let me know the status.

Comment: It’s not angular but. The website can be a regular html website also. It should be able to detect the text I provide to it to find

Comment: can also be `<button onclick="__doPostBack('LoginButton','')" id="LoginButton" type="submit" class="loginbutton">Log in</button>`

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by using the following code:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[translate(normalize-space(text()),'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')='{0}']".format(text))
```